# Finding $n$th derivative in an unusual way

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, functions, derivatives, cauchy-integral-formula

If $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-1}$, then $f^{(4)}(z)$ can be found by differentiating $f(z)$ four times. I tried to use Cauchy's integral formula, but the integrand is not holomorphic at $z=0$, so we can't use it in this case. What can possibly be another clever method of finding the 4th (or $n$th derivative) of this function using an indirect approach?

Comment: Do you mean that the integrand is not holomorphic at $z=1$ and $z=-1$? It is in fact holomorphic in the unit disc, so you can use Cauchy's integral formula, and then get the result by analytic continuation.

Comment: Why don't you think it's holomorphic at $z=0$?

Comment: $f(z)$ is of course holomorphic at $z=0$, but the integrand will not be holomorphic at that point. I, however, have probably confused the concepts - we need not care about the integrand itself being holomorphic at a certain point, but only about $f(z)$.

Comment: What integrand?

Comment: $f^{(4)}(0) = \frac{4!}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{e^{iz}}{(z^2-1)z^5}dz$

Comment: In that case, note that if the integrand was holomorphic, then the integral would be $0$ by Cauchy's theorem. That integrand will never be holomorphic in the domain enclosed by $\gamma$ by construction, and that is precisely what gives us the result.

Comment: So it's only the fourth derivative at $0$ that you want?

Comment: @RobertIsrael yes

Comment: @solstafir what result?

Comment: @sequence Cauchy's integral formula. It's related to the residue theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(z^2-1) f(z) = e^{iz}$$
Differentiate this four times:
$$ \eqalign{2 z f(z) + (z^2-1) f'(z) &= i e^{iz}\cr
            2 f(z) + 4 z f'(z) + (z^2-1) f''(z)  &= -e^{iz}\cr
            6 f'(z) + 8 z f''(z) + (z^2-1) f'''(z) &= -i e^{iz}\cr
            14 f''(z) + 16 z f'''(z) + (z^2-1) f''''(z) &= e^{iz}\cr}$$
Now substitute $z=0$: 
$$ \eqalign{-f(0) &= 1\cr -f'(0) &= i\cr 2 f(0) - f''(0) &= -1\cr
   6 f'(0) - f'''(0) &= -i\cr
   14 f''(0) - f''''(0) &= 1\cr}$$
so that
$$\eqalign{f(0) &= -1\cr
           f'(0) &= -i\cr
           f''(0) &= -1\cr
           f'''(0) &= -5i\cr
           f''''(0) &= -13\cr}$$

Answer (score 2):

May be, another way : since you want the derivatives for $z=0$, you could use Taylor expansion of $e^{x}$ and replace $x$ by $iz$; this would give $$e^{iz}=1+i z-\frac{z^2}{2}-\frac{i z^3}{6}+\frac{z^4}{24}+\frac{i
   z^5}{120}+O\left(z^6\right)$$ Now, use long division to get $$f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2-1}=-1-i z-\frac{1}{2}z^2-\frac{5 i }{6}z^3-\frac{13 }{24}z^4-\frac{101 i
   }{120}z^5+O\left(z^6\right)$$ and use $$f(z)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{z^i}{i!}f^{(i)}(0)$$ Then, identification becomes simple and leads to the results already given by Robert Israel in his answer.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Lets $\ds{\verts{z} < 1}$:

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mathrm{f}\pars{z}} & = {\expo{\ic z} \over z^{2}-1} =
 \overbrace{%
\bracks{-\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\pars{z^{2}}^{k}}}^{\ds{1 \over z^{2} - 1}}\
\overbrace{\bracks{\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{\ic z}^{n} \over n!}}}
^{\ds{\expo{\ic z}}}\ =\
-\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\ic^{n} \over n!}z^{n + 2k}
\\[3mm] & =
-\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\sum_{n = 2k}^{\infty}
{\ic^{n - 2k} \over \pars{n - 2k}!}z^{n} =
-\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}z^{n}\,\ic^{n}\sum_{k = 0}^{k\ \leq\ n/2}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{n - 2k}!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\bracks{-\ic^{n}n!\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{n - 2k}!}}{z^{n} \over n!}
\end{align}

---

$$
\begin{array}{|c|}\hline\mbox{}\\ 
\ds{\quad\color{#f00}{\mathrm{f}^{\mathrm{\pars{n}}}\pars{0}} =
\color{#f00}{-\ic^{n}n!\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor n/2\right\rfloor}
{\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{n - 2k}!}}\quad}
\\ \mbox{}\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

> By the way,
>   $$
> \color{#f00}{\mathrm{f}^{\mathrm{\pars{4}}}\pars{0}} =
> -\ic^{4}\,4!\sum_{k = 0}^{2}
> {\pars{-1}^{k} \over \pars{4 - 2k}!} =
> -24\pars{{1 \over 4!} - {1 \over 2!} + {1 \over 0!}} =
> \color{#f00}{-13}
> $$